# How do I give back reputation points awarded for answering a question?

Tags: feature-request

I was just awarded rep points for answering a question, and I would like to give them back. It is a personal thing in that I do not wish to have any reputation that someone else earned. I only want the rep that I have received. Is there a way that I can return them to their rightful earner?

Comment: Were you awarded a bounty? Which post are you talking about?

Comment: Are you familiar with this: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/bounty? If someone gave you a bounty then they believe that your answer deserved the extra rep. So that sounds like earning to me.

Comment: @fredsbend yes I am aware of the bounty, and that was the source of 50 reps, however My personal feelings are that I only want reps that I earn, and if he gives me some of his reps he is giving me the acclaim of others for something he wrote. I do not deserve that acclaim, nor do I wish to have them. I do thank you for your guidance in this matter, but it has not altered my standards.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you are referring to the bounty awarded to one of your answers by user [atherises](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/16593/atherises).

The easiest solution to what you are requesting, is to identify a post from this user that you deem appropriate to award a bounty to and reciprocate accordingly. Whether you *should* do that is another matter - surely any bounty awarded to you by a legitimate user is actually rightfully earned by you? Additionally, why shouldn't a user have a choice about what they invest their reputation in - if they've earned it, why should you hinder them from being able to freely allocate it according to their own wishes?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no quarrel  with the bounty system, only in my case I feel I have not earned them. The answer I gave was given where I was not aware of the bounty. There is one more consideration on my part those reps were from others for something he wrote that they felt was worthy of their acknowledgement, so actually he is giving me someone else's acclaim, to which I am not entitled. Incidentally you are correct about the award of his bounty. This is not intended to reflect on anyone else or the validity of a bounty system. It is just personal.

Comment: @Bye Well, since you just don't want it open a bounty on a question and get rid of the 50 rep by giving it to someone else. Bruised reed has suggested that you find an answer by atherises that is good and you can give it back that way. However, might I suggest that I have some pretty good answers, myself? ;)

Comment: I don't see why you say he's awarding you for someone else's work. When you wrote that I thought you meant someone had edited your answer and improved it greatly, but there's no edits on the answer!

Comment: @curiousdannii He is giving me points which he earned. those points were awarded to him by others for his achievements those who gave them wanted him to have them and not me.